# Is it possible to create an empty C# solution in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 for C#, when starting with empty, I didn't see that I can create a new solution, but only a new project.

- If that is true, why is that? How can I create a solution then, to include one or more  existing projects?
- If not true, how can I create a solution starting from empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. 
I see the blank solution can be created as

- Launch Visual Studio
- File > New Project > Templates > Other Project
  Types > Visual Studio Solutions > Blank Solutions
  [image]

Once you create the solution, you can add any type of projects to it.

Comment: Thanks. How can I add an existing project to an existing nonempty solution? Is there requirement on what kinds of projects can be added to a solution and what kinds of projects can't be?

Comment: @Tim Right click on the solution in visual studio > Add > Existing Project and navigate to your existing your project folder.  Solutions are usually just like containers so you should be able to add any types of visual studio projects to it as long as they are compatible with the visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions are independent of the projects.

Do the following to create a solution:

Open Visual Studio

- File-->New Project

On New Project window:

- Templates-->Other Project Types-->Visual Studio Solutions-->Blank
  Solutions

Comment: who down voted for me?. Please check the answer time. Mine is the first answer.